# I just want to return JSON error response when ever the token field is missing in headers in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

Just simply want whenever my Api is called if token is missing it should return a json response that "Token is required"
i'm getting the token in headers
let me explain it with sample code:

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
$token = $headers['User-Token'];
if(isset($token)){
  $user_details = $this->user_basic_model->get_user_by_token($token);
  if (!empty($user_details))
  {
   $data = $this->fare_model->get_all_fare();

   if (empty($data)) {
       $arr = array('msg' => 'Error!', 'status_code' => 404);
       echo json_encode($arr);
    } 
   else {
       $success_array = array('msg' => 'Success!', 'status_code' => 200);
       echo json_encode(array_merge($data, $success_array));
      }
  }
  else
  {
   $arr = array('success' => 'false', 'msg' => 'Unauthorize Request', 
   'status_code' => 401);
   echo json_encode($arr);
  }
 }
 else
  {
   $arr = array('success' => 'false', 'msg' => 'Token is required', 
   'status_code' => 401);
   echo json_encode($arr);
  }
```

in this case when i don't send User-Token field in headers using postman i got the response properly but with that response i'm getting an error of undefined index "User-token"
i don't want this error to be shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just modify your code little bit.

```
if (isset($headers['User-Token'])) {
    $token = $headers['User-Token'];
    if (empty($token)) {
        //your code
    } else {
        $arr = array('success' => 'false', 'msg' => 'Token is required',
            'status_code' => 401);
        echo json_encode($arr);
        exit();
    }
} else {
    $arr = array('success' => 'false', 'msg' => 'Token is required',
        'status_code' => 401);
    echo json_encode($arr);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: thanks alot @urfusion i have marked your answer as solution :)